# tcpdf make image full width in header or footer

Tags: image, tcpdf

I am having trouble while adding an full width image in header and footer.

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<img src="./images/bottom.png" alt="banner" class="CToWUd a6T" style="width: 660px; height: 200px;">
EOD;
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, it will apply image and change background color for header and footer

```
public function Footer() {
  $img_file = 'img/myimg.png';
  $this->Image($img_file, 5, 3, 50, 15, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
  $this->Rect(0, $this->getPageHeight() - 10, $this->getPageWidth(), 30, 'F', "",  array(30, 127, 184)); 
}

public function Header() {
    $img_file = 'img/myimg.png';
    $this->Image($img_file, 5, 3, 50, 15, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
    $this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(), 20,'F',array(),array(30, 127, 184));
}
```

For more options you can review example from tcpdf https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_051/

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use SetHTMLFooter and negative margins:

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<footer style="margin: 0 -20px;">
<img src="./images/bottom.png" alt="banner" class="CToWUd a6T" style="width: 660px; height: 200px;">
</footer>
EOD;
$pdf->SetHTMLFooter($tbl);
```